# SMS Trigger Possible from Journey Builder?

Tags: sms

I am looking into SMS triggers and trying to figure out the logic.  We have our platform connected to SF and in  Journey Builder there are boxes like "is created" or "is updated"

If a user is created, can this theoretically trigger a SMS?  I understand there are api calls which can be used using transactional messaging api, but to simplify I wanted to instead just send a SMS if a checkbox is ticked inside Salesforce.  I have tried using iscreated/is updated inside the Journey but it does appear to send any SMS :(

Comment: it is possible to send a SMS. Please check if you have a field with phone type and a locale type field for the object which you are trying to send a SMS. Also, check the Field level security for those fields.

Comment: I definitely have a correct phone. I clicked "is updated" as the action.  I then filtered on my own uuid and for entry data - Contact:Owner:contact:phone - still no SMS :(

Comment: Below troubleshoot can help.1. Did you tried with normal data extension to send a SMS?
2. Make sure you have locale field type in the object which you are referring to send.
3. While configuring SMS, did you check 'subscribe all contacts to keyword' and selected a keyword?
4. In the journey setting select the phone number attribute
5. I hope the short code/long code you are using for SMS in the same region/country your mobile number as well right?

Comment: I am using a salesforce data object which should trigger a SMS, unfortunately we wont be able to use a data extension as this is triggered from Salesforce.  I am basically ticking boxes inside SF and seeing if it will trigger an SMS.  Is this not an avenue we can take?

For selecting the phone attribute, there are so many options, is use mobile number from contacts not preferred?  I tried that too - thanks!  Right now I am selecting use number from entry source: Contact:Phone and in FILTER CRITERIA, I put the UUID from Salesforce, so user uuid = blabhalbhalh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely a standard use case. If yours isn't working, I'd review for starters:

1. Your Journey "Event Results" data to make sure your Entry Event is actually detecting the desired data change over in CRM.
2. Whether the relevant contacts you are sending to have opted in to your shortcode already (or are you building an opt-in campaign?).
3. Your MobileConnect records for the phone numbers you're sending to (look up the Subscriber Key for a particular contact that made it through the Journey according to your Event Results data.) Maybe MobileConnect actually did send the SMS but something downstream prevented receipt of the SMS.